# Integral of the normal distribution multiplied with a density function

Tags: integration, analysis, normal-distribution

I am trying to solve an integral. This integral is pretty difficult to solve. I tried it with the help of an integral calculator, but the calculator shows the solution with the error function.... I have to show that$$\int \frac{1}{2 \pi d^2} \exp \left(- \frac{(x - w)^2}{d^2} \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} \exp \left( -\frac{w^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right) \, dw = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi d^2(2\sigma^2+d^2)}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} \frac{x}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 + \frac{d^2}{2}} } \right).$$

Comment: Your calculator probably thought you meant an indefinite integral, whereas you probably want the definite integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!